# How to select/click respective row within a table? There are a few tables on the page

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

there are a few tables on the page. In one of them I need to select respective company code and then proceed. I have a problem with the following code. I don't know what approach should I use and if I get the correct company code, then how to click in it?

```
 public void selectCompanyCodeFromTable(String companyCode){
        int rowCount = shoppingCart.companyCodeTable.size();
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
            String sCellValue = driver.findElement(By.tagName("tr")).getText();

            if (sCellValue.equalsIgnoreCase(companyCode)) {
                System.out.println("Found the respective company code");

                //How to click/select this particular row?

            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add the HTML code for the table? Also, please add any error message you are receiving, or describe what happens when you try to run the code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You already found the element that contains the company code, right? So, if that is a button, use the same findElement() method to click it:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("tr")).click();
```